# how to read text file in folder with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, io

I have a folder structure like this

```
index.html
file.txt
```

in the `index.html` I have a script that wants to read the `file.txt` and assign it to a variable, say `x`.

```js
async function loadFile(file) {
    let text = await file.text();
    console.log(text);
    return text
}

var x = loadFile("file.txt")
```

but this returns an error

```
main.js:35 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: file.text is not a function
    at loadFile (main.js:35:27)
    at main.js:39:13
```

what to do? I just want to assign `file.txt` content to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript in browser doesn't give you direct access to file system.
What you did is just pass a string to your function and call `text()` on it. Sadly it doesn't work like that.

Here are two workarounds I know of:

### 1. fetch api

If you have an http server serving your files then you make a request using `fetch()` to obtain its content in JS. Read the docs here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Note that it won't work on pages loaded with `file://` URI scheme. You need http(s). If you have python installed run `python -m http.server 8000` in directory containing files to be served.

### 2. FileReader

If the file is to be selected by user as input to a form then you can use `FileReader`

Have a look these links:
webdev has great explaination for this

https://web.dev/read-files/

also see the docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: thanks, this is pretty much solved!!! I didn't know it can't use ```file://``` and had to use ```python -m http.server```.